# Why do my transactions get mined when the recipient is a non existent contract?

Tags: transactions

When I am sending a transaction to a smart contract which doesn't exists yet for example my transaction is getting mined and I get no error or false returned. Is this an always expected behavior for such transactions?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, because you are simply sending data along with your transaction. This can be anything from function parameters to simply a message.

If the address you are targeting contains code, then the code stored in the contract is executed. In that code, it can read and parse your transaction data and use that as function parameters.

If there is no code, then it's simply data. Ethereum could enforce not allowing any data to be sent if there exists no code, but I guess decided not to. As mentioned before, this has been used to simply send messages.